# Find the derivative of a piecewise function.

Tags: limits, derivatives

[image]

I would just like to know if my proof here is valid. I know I left out some computational details, but I'm more concerned about the structure of the proof than those details.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you made a mistake in iii. That is not the left-hand limit you want to be looking at. The conclusion is correct, but the reasoning for the conclusion is not.

In ii. you can be a bit fancier and use the formula for a derivative of a polynomial. The point is that the derivative is a local calculation, so if your function is $x^2$ for $x>0$, then for the purpose of differentiation you can pretend your function is $x^2$ everywhere as long as you're differentiating at $x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

For Case 3, where you are evaluating $\displaystyle\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}$, you should be clear that you are evaluating the limit of $\frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h}$ when $x=0$. As it is currently written, you are apparently evaluating both sides of the limit using the negative side of the function, which is invalid. You need to show that $\frac{d0}{dx}=\frac{dx^2}{dx}$ where $x=0$.

Besides that, your proof (outline) seems good.

Comment: Ok, so then I will have $\frac{x^2 + 2xh + h^2 - x^2}{h} = h$ when x = 0, so the limit as h goes to 0 from the right would be 0. Correct?